# Copy a Pivot Table with VBA

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table

I'm programming an excel macro that is supposed to create tables and graphs in a new summary worksheet, and I'm having a problem in a part where the macro needs to filter a Pivot Table, and then copy/paste it in the summary worksheet. Sounds simple, but for a reason I get just a single cell with value 0 in the destination range. The filtering is done right, however. Here's the part of the code where this happens.

```
    Dim pt As PivotTable: Set pt = errprov.PivotTables("ErroresProveedor")
    On Error Resume Next
    pt.PivotFields("DESCRIPCIONESGLOBALES").ClearAllFilters
    pt.PivotFields("DESCRIPCIONESGLOBALES").CurrentPage =actual.Range("A2").Value
    pt.PivotFields("DATA DE").ClearAllFilters
    pt.PivotFields("DATA DE").CurrentPage = "SA"

    'The problem is here
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = errprov.Range("A7", Range("A7").End(xlToRight).End(xlDown))
    actual.Activate
    rng.Copy Range("A" & fila)
```

I get an error with the range property, probably because there's a Pivot Table there, but I have also tried selecting the table as an object with its own method, like I found in other posts, and I get the same result (Single cell with value 0).

Comment: Do you assign a value to `fila`?

Comment: every value has been assigned correctly, I ran the macro step-by-step and fila has the value I want. The problem is that when I copy the table, I get the 0 on the A & fila (122) cell.

Comment: Comment out `On Error Resume Next` and see if there is an error.

Comment: Did it, the exact message error is "Error in the Range method of the Worksheet object" (traducted from spanish).

Comment: I'm not hopeful but does this make it go away? `Set rng = errprov.Range("A7", errprov.Range("A7").End(xlToRight).End(xlDown))` Are there formulas in the cells you are copying?

Comment: Bit odd that people feel the need to remove the OP expressing gratitude for any help forthcoming. I rejected the edit - presumably somebody else thought differently.

Comment: @SJR Thought the same with the edit request, thought it was some kind of rule or something here, it is my first post. Btw, your solution did not work, thank you very much for trying to help anyways.

Comment: The edit was simply for Reputation points, not needed at all! I agree with you @SJR! Very odd indeed.

Comment: @Xabier - talk about perverse incentives!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Set rng = errprov.Range("A7", Range("A7").End(xlToRight).End(xlDown))
```

should be

```
Set rng = errprov.Range("A7:" & Range("A7").End(xlToRight).End(xlDown).Address)
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked, partially though. The table was copied to the range i specified, but just the first 2 columns. I think it might be a problem with .End, but when i use Ctrl+Shift+ArrowKey to select the table manually (It is supposed to work the same as .End), I get to select it whole. Any idea why is this happening?

Comment: When you do it manually are you going right and then down, or down and then right?. Your code is doing the former. Ctrl+Shift+ArrowKey stops just before the first blank cell it encounters so it sounds as if c7 is blank

Comment: I'm going right and down manually, that's the weird part. I'm going to try to do it down and then right in the macro to see if it works then.

Comment: I get exactly the same partial-table at destination when I do it first down and then right.